# R's order equivalent in python

Tags: python, r, python-2.7

Any ideas what is the python's equivalent for R's `order`?

```
order(c(10,2,-1, 20), decreasing = F) 
# 3 2 1 4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In numpy there is a function named `argsort`

```
import numpy as np
lst = [10,2,-1,20]
np.argsort(lst)
# array([2, 1, 0, 3])
```

Note that python list index starting at 0 while starting at 1 in R.

Answer (score 9):

It is [`numpy.argsort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([10,2,-1, 20])
a.argsort()

# array([2, 1, 0, 3])
```

and if you want to explore the `decreasing = T` option. You can try,

```
(-a).argsort()

#array([3, 0, 1, 2])
```